Receiving an error after running sudo apt update in Ubuntu Server 24.04
Umm I'm very new to this, just a nerd teen so it would be appreciated if things were explained a bit... comprehensively maybe? I downloaded Ubuntu Server LTS 24.04, everything went smoothly. When i logged in and ran sudo apt update, i get the error
Hit:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Translation-en
Ign:5 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted Translation-en
Ign:6 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Translation-en
Ign:7 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Translation-en
Get:4 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Translation-en [513 kB]
Err:4 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main Translation-en
  File has unexpected size (519008 != 513060). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 103.151.111.245 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:513060 [weak]
   - SHA256:76912463cba2c79e7a9cc0f45ff74ecc265eac99a615ffa50f11b380aad33800
   - SHA1:9c70f864f73e903a9510e9212320116cc37d9b0a [weak]
   - MD5Sum:7285d05f4db10cc4c74002add0b01e3f [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 23 Apr 2024 08:44:21 +0000
Get:5 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted Translation-en [19.3 kB]
Err:5 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/restricted Translation-en

Get:6 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Translation-en [5,981 kB]
Err:6 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe Translation-en

Get:7 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Translation-en [118 kB]
Err:7 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse Translation-en

Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/i18n/Translation-en.xz  File has unexpected size (519008 != 513060). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 103.151.111.245 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:513060 [weak]
    - SHA256:76912463cba2c79e7a9cc0f45ff74ecc265eac99a615ffa50f11b380aad33800
    - SHA1:9c70f864f73e903a9510e9212320116cc37d9b0a [weak]
    - MD5Sum:7285d05f4db10cc4c74002add0b01e3f [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 23 Apr 2024 08:44:21 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/universe/i18n/Translation-en.xz
E: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en.xz
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

I am not sure what information i am supposed to give, so just ask me what i need to give and i'll try to respond ASAP. I even tried reinstalling Ubuntu-Server but i get the same error. So help is appreciated!
P.S. Not sure if this helps but using Dell Lattitude 7400, just did a BIOS upgrade and apt version is apt 2.7.14 (amd64).I downloaded this to host a Minecraft server with docker. Anything else? Like a log or something?
P.S.2 I forgot something, when i downloaded Ubuntu Server, i encountered a error in end of Installation, however when that error actually happened was when curtin installer was doing some updates, i am not sure how to find that error log again. But when i booted into ubuntu, it allowed me to login, and i was suprised.
EDIT:I get 404 error like when I try installing neofetch or xinit which I need.
  404  Not Found [IP: 103.151.111.245 80]
Err:2 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 libfftw3-double3 amd64 3.3.10-1ubuntu3

the error is way longer should I post it all here?

Sorry but I wasn't able to post the error for sm reason, I edited it and now it works.

I meant that I was able to post the error now

I guess I'll be using Release 22.04 until I figure out the solution.

Everything in your output suggests that your mirror is updating (synchronizing from the main servers), or possibly being maintained.
Your output specifically mentions this most common possibility: Mirror sync in progress?
A sync takes a few minutes. Just be patient: Wait a few minutes and try again.
Or switch to a different mirror.
If the issue persists more than one hour, then try a different mirror.

thank you that was very helpful, works perfectly now.
